# Converting US Treasury CMT to Discount Yields

Tags: yield-curve, bond-yields

I'd like to convert the US Treasury Constant Maturity series (par, semi-annual coupon, Actual/365 daycount convention) into Discount Factors (for appropriate comparison for certain money-market series, calculation of forward rates, conversion to alternative daycounts, etc.).

The "hypothetical security" reflecting the CMT quote is straightforward for 6 months to 30 years: $PV=FaceValue$ that pays $FaceValue * CMT
Rate/2$ every 6 months before maturity, $FaceValue*(1+CMTRate/2)$ at maturity (even on weekends/holidays, since it's an interpolated curve).

What is the hypothetical security for the 1, 2, and 3 month CMT quotes? Is it a discount bond (and, if so, what's the discount formula to arrive at $PV$)? Or is it a coupon bond with $PV=FaceValue$ that pays $FaceValue*(1+CMTRate * YearFrac365)$ at maturity?

Comment: I'm asking pretty much the same [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77277/convert-us-treasury-par-yields-to-spot-rates), I've only seen this later, so not strictly an answer here. Can you please elaborate a little bit more on the longer maturities (as the shorter ones are being covered by the answer): what spot rate do you use to discount the semiannual payments? Don't you need to bootstrap by interpolating between CM par rates and evaluating a par rate at payment maturities?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a coupon bond with semiannual coupons of $CMTRate$, thus a payment of $FaceValue*(1+CMTRate/2)$ at maturity and no other payments due.  The $PV$ of this bond is $FaceValue*CashflowatMaturity/(1+CMTRate/2)^{2*YearFrac365}$

Comment: Interesting. So you'd "overpay" the coupon on 1-month and 3-month bills (by taking 0.5 years of simple interest) and let PV adjust upward from face value accordingly? I guess that makes the PV a dirty price on these quotes (having accrued 3-5 months of interest)?